# Computer runs out of memory once the program connects to the tcp server

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

My program allocates huge memory until my computer runs out of it. Attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

ReadMessages() method is called from an infinite loop for reading any data from server.
After connecting to the tcp server, my system memory usage increases and runs out of memory after certain point of time.

From my understanding I know I am **allocating 8192 bytes of array (byte[] byDataIn) every time**, however they should get unallocated once the control gets out of scope.

I tried making the **byte[] byDataIn** variable as class member, but ReadMessages() method throw error saying insuffient buffer.

I am new to C# so kindlyy excuse me from asking silly questions.

```
 public class TCPClientClass
    {
        NetworkStream Sender;
        NetworkStream Receiver;
        //private StreamReader SrReciever;
        private Thread thrMessaging;
        TcpClient tcp;
        bool connected = false;
        String strCommand = String.Empty;
        //byte[] byDataIn;
        byte[] byDataOut;
        Queue qQueueIn;
        Queue qQueueOut;
        private static Mutex muQueueIn   = new Mutex();
        private static Mutex muQueueOut  = new Mutex();
        String responseData = String.Empty;
        String sendData = String.Empty;
        public TCPClientClass()
        {
            qQueueIn    = new Queue();
            qQueueOut   = new Queue();
        }

        private String StrCommand { get { return strCommand; } set { strCommand = value; } }

        public bool Connected { get { return connected; } set { connected = value; } }
        //public bool Connect(IPAddress IP, int nPortNo)
        public async Task<bool> Connect(IPAddress IP, int nPortNo)
        {
            tcp = new TcpClient();
            //byDataIn = new byte[tcp.ReceiveBufferSize];
            byDataOut = new byte[tcp.SendBufferSize];
            try
            {
                await tcp.ConnectAsync(IP, nPortNo);
                thrMessaging = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunction));
                thrMessaging.Start();
                Connected = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server");
            }
            return connected;
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            Sender?.Close();
            Receiver?.Close();
            tcp?.Close();
            thrMessaging.Abort();
            Connected = false;
        }
        private void ThreadFunction()
        {
            while (thrMessaging.IsAlive)
                DoTasks();
        }
        private void DoTasks()
        {
            if (Connected)
            {
                var a = ReadMessages();
                var b = SendMessages();
            }
        }

        private /*void*/async Task ReadMessages()
        {
            Receiver = tcp.GetStream();

            if (Receiver.CanRead)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] byDataIn = new byte[tcp.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    var response = await Receiver.ReadAsync(byDataIn, 0, byDataIn.Length);

                    //add the data to the queue
                    muQueueIn.WaitOne();
                    responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byDataIn);                    
                    qQueueIn.Enqueue(responseData);
                    Array.Clear(byDataIn, 0, byDataIn.Length);
                    muQueueIn.ReleaseMutex();

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task  SendMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCommand))
                {
                    byDataOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strCommand);
                    Sender = tcp.GetStream();

                    await Sender.WriteAsync(byDataOut, 0, byDataOut.Length);
                    Sender.Flush();
                    strCommand = String.Empty;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }                    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public void AddCommand(String strCmd)
        {
            StrCommand = strCmd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. You're adding the received data to a queue, correct? Are you sure that queue is being processed and the memory released from it? Can you show that code, please?

Comment: As an aside, you need to *use* `response`. It tells you how much of `byDataIn` actually contains any data received.

Comment: @AdamBenson my program had same problem before I added the queue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how do i use the response. Also i will add the entire program

Comment: You are creating new mutexes (muQueueIn/Out) for every instance of TCPClientClass, but you store them in a static.

Comment: @GvS thanks.. modified the same

Comment: @apb_developer What did you modify? Removed the static, or test if the mutex exists before creating?

Comment: @GvS I created the mutex only once as a static member and not in the constructor